# How to take ScreenShot Of UIView Which is not in memory iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to convert `UIView` to `UIImage`, in which the view is in background and when I checked view hierarchy, it is there as white space, probably it wont get loaded..
What I wanted to do is load the view into memory and convert into image.

Comment: you need to render the view first to take a screenshot of it; the system renders the view for you if it goes to the navigation stack and it is about to appear; if these conditions are not good enough for you, I'm afraid of you may need to create an own custom renderer at your convenience, using e.g. `CoreGraphics`.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to initialize your view with your required frame and then pass to below code as targetView. Initialize your view before you call screen capture method like below

```
UIView *targetView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)]; //Initilization
UIImage *capturedImage = [self captureScreen:targetView]; //Call method


- (UIImage *)captureScreen:(UIView*)targetView
{
    UIView* captureView = targetView;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(captureView.bounds.size, captureView.opaque, 0.0);
    [captureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 ,captureView.frame.size.width ,captureView.frame.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size, captureView.opaque, 1.2f);
    [screenshot drawInRect:cropRect];
    UIImage * customScreenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return customScreenShot;
}
```

Comment: still not working.. im getting black screen as image

Comment: can you share your whole code of initialize and screen capture

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
- (UIImage*)snapShot:(UIView*)myView {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.frame.size);
    [myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```